# Plotting a multicolored density plot in Seaborn based on a condition

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a kernel density graph that changes color at a certain point.

I have a continuous variable ranging from -3 to 3 and want the data below 0 to appear as a blue line and shaded region and above 0 to be red.  I've tried creating a list or series of colors corresponding to each of the points in my data, but Seaborn's `kdeplot` color option doesn't seem to allow an array.  I've also tried grouping the data above and below 0, but this plots two obviously separate distributions, where I want only one.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sample = np.random.uniform(low=-3.0, high=3.0, size=(100,))
df = pd.DataFrame(sample, columns = ['scores'])

def plot_group(group):
    global ax
    c = 'b' if (group['scores'] < 0).all() else 'r'
    sns.kdeplot(group['scores'], color = c, shade = True)

colors = np.where(df['scores'] < 0, 'b', 'r')
df.groupby(colors).apply(plot_group)
sns.despine(top = True, right = True, left = True)
plt.setp(axes, yticks=[])
```

I expect a single continuous distribution which is colored differently around zero, but what I am getting is two separate plots.
[Here's the incorrect output that I'm generating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWdA2.png)

Comment: Seaborn does not provide any option for this. You can calculate the kde of the data and plot it as [a multicolored line](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html).

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar with a bar chart, I needed to color the bar with the greatest value red, this was done like this.

```
import seaborn as sns

colors = ['grey' if (x < max(values)) else 'red' for x in values ]
sns.barplot(x=labels, y=values, palette=colors)
```